# HtmlService generated script gadget: hyperlinks don't work

Tags: google-apps-script

i've created a simple apps script gadget in my google site, and it generates the output using HtmlService. In the source file, there is a dirt simple hyperlink

`<a href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>`

when i click it, i get a report in the debug window:

`The page at https://sites.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzw0jd06fDrbZ-KkjKmDvPKma_RZnboxe0iX…U6mS841TC3C&bc=transparent&f=Aclonica,sans-serif&tc=%23cccccc&lc=%23336699 displayed insecure content from http://google.com/. exec:1`

`The page at https://sites.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzw0jd06fDrbZ-KkjKmDvPKma_RZnboxe0iX…U6mS841TC3C&bc=transparent&f=Aclonica,sans-serif&tc=%23cccccc&lc=%23336699 displayed insecure content from http://www.google.com/. exec:1`

`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. exec:1`

any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is open google.com inside your Apps Script gadget embedded in a Google Site. As the error message suggests, the `X-Frame-Options` doesn't allow this. 
So, you should add a target attribute to you `<a>` tag to open in a new or the parent window

For example,

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_parent">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Comment: for target="_parent" i get: `The page at https://sites.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzw0jd06fDrbZ-KkjKmDvPKma_RZnboxe0iX…TykLqS3y8xm&bc=transparent&f=Aclonica,sans-serif&tc=%23cccccc&lc=%23336699 displayed insecure content from http://www.google.com/.`

`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. `

Comment: for target="_blank", it seems to cooperate properly. thank you!

Comment: part of the problem was also that i was doing this programmatically in JS, and apparently you have to use `a.setAttribute("target","_blank")` on "a" elements. I was trying to do `a.target="_blank"`